# How to fix "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" error while posting on facebook wal

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" error when posting message on user's facebook wall. I am using facebook graph API. I have also set the "publish_actions" permission in the scope, but didn't working. My code is

```
require 'facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => APP_ID,
            'secret' => APP_SECRET,
            ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    try {
        //create message with token gained before
        $post =  array(
            'access_token' => $accessToken,
            'message' => 'Test message'
        );

        $res = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_actions'
    ));
    header("Location: " . $login_url);
}
```

Can you please suggest me what i am missing in the code or in the app?

Comment: debug the access token and make sure the permission is included and the token is valid

Comment: Yes, the permission is included and access token is correct. Facebook login is working fine with this script. Problem is coming when i am posting message on facebook wall. Also everything is working fine from administrator account(facebook account from which i created the app), but when i am using different facebook account it is not working and getting the same error. Please suggest ASAP.

Comment: well, that was the most important part....writing an answer now

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that it does work for Admins, but not for anyone else, it´s very clear what the problem is: You need to go through Login Review with `publish_actions` - else, that permission will only work for users with a role in the App.

All the information you need about Login Review is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: We checked the referenced document, but didn't find any solution. I am still not able to post on facebook. Is their a way to change the role in the app for all users, so all users can post on facebook? Please suggest.

Comment: everything you need to know can be found in the link you posted. without review, publish_actions will only work for users with a role in the app. you can add users as tester, admin or developer to make the permission work for them, but you can´t just set a "default role" for everyone. that would make the whole review process senseless.

Comment: Hi, Luschn, Thanks for your reply. You mean i need to send the app review on facebook for this permission to make it working for all users?

Comment: Hi Luschn, here is my website link for which i am unable to pust on facebook. Please check the user not authorize error on this page.http://web3.anzleads.com/zf/public/index.php/

Comment: that is exactly what i mean, and that is exactly what my answer is about: you need to go through the review process with publish_actions to make it work for all users. please open the link in my answer and read ALL the content. it is explained in detail in the docs.

Comment: Hi Luschn, Thank you for your reply. I have read the link you referred me and using the permission as in the reference document, but still getting "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" error for authorization. I am not sure how to authorize users for app. I have also checked the accress token and it is correct.

Comment: as i said several times: you need to send publish_actions to review, or it will not work.

Comment: don´t forget to click on ALL links in the article i posted too. ("what is login review?", "how to submit...", ...)